# Multiple relation to same model on cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, model

I am trying to make multiple relation on model as describes in cake kbook
I have two model Account and Tax like this

Account(id, name, code)
Tax(id.name, sales_tax_gl, purchase_tax_gl)

both sales_tax_gl and purchase_tax_gl related to Account.id
these are the model I have created

```
class Tax extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Tax';
var $displayField = 'name';

var $belongsTo = array(
    'SalesTax' => array(
        'className' => 'Account',
        'foreignKey' => 'sales_tax_gl',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'PurchaseTax' => array(
        'className' => 'Account',
        'foreignKey' => 'purchase_tax_gl',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
}


Account Model
class Account extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Account';
var$primaryKey = 'id';


var $hasMany = array(        
    'TaxSalesTax' => array(            
    'className' => 'Tax',            
    'foreignKey' => 'sales_tax_gl' ),        
    'TaxPurchaseTax' => array(            
    'className' => 'Tax',            
    'foreignKey' => 'purchase_tax_gl' ) 

);

}
```

But it fails with this message "Warning (2): pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "Account"

What'swrong with the model? I am using postgreSql, thank for your help

Comment: Your error is related to a query, yet you've provided no code related to a query.  That might help! :)

Comment: it is simple query, just $this->Tax->find('all'), am  I wrong? thank

Answer (score 0):

In first model your model name is SalesTax and in the second one (Account Model) the model name is TaxSalesTax,please correct it into the correct one and try.

Comment: Hi thank, it is the same,still error. i don't know cake book example define the same with I denifine.

Comment: Hi in which controller you are getting the error?can you post the save query here ?

Comment: Sanjay, The erro comes from Tax controller when i try to query using $this->Tax->find('all)

Comment: and this is the error when I test in ppstgres query:Warning (2): pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "Account"

Answer (score 0):

I  am thinking that i found the problem. That's cause I use virtual fields in account model like below

```
var $name = 'Account';
var $primaryKey = 'id';
var $displayField = 'name';
var $order=array('Account.id');
var $virtualFields = array('dropdown_name' => 'Account.id || \' \' || Account.name');
```

when I uncomment $virtualFields it work as it should, but I still don't know why?

Comment: finally I know. We should override model to Using virtualField with model alias.Thank to All

Comment: Right, more info is found here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-and-model-aliases